# Can a Nexus 6P be factory reset when screen cannot be used and phone off?

Tags: factory-reset, broken-screen, android-device-manager, nexus-6p, remote-wipe

I broke my Nexus 6P screen, so am replacing it - usually I would factory the phone. However, I can't as the screen is completely black.

I power cycled the phone, but I am unable to enter the pattern to unlock the phone (fingerprint scanner only works after you enter the pattern after restart).

I used Android Device Manager to wipe it, but as I can't decrypt it through entering my pattern, it isn't online, so can't be wiped.

**However, does any of this matter if the pattern can't be entered after power cycling?** Surely the device is encrypted so my data is secure. And if anyone manages to guess my pattern, the device will be online and ADB will wipe it.

Should I do anything else?

Comment: Take a look at our [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info). I remember there was a way via ADB to "reset" the pattern (to "none"), which might work in your case as well. Apart from which, it could be possible utilizing [fastboot](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fastboot/info) to do the wipe. Not sure concerning encryption here, but might be worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter the password wrong too many times on your nexus device, it will factory reset your data (by default). It is also possible to factory reset through recovery mode by turning phone off, holding power and down volume simultaneously, clicking volume buttons until hitting recovery mode, then clicking factory reset.

Comment: Thanks - I can't enter anything on the screen though, and I am unable to see when the option for factory reset is highlighted in recovery mode.

Comment: OK it is a bit tricky but then you have to just click volume button and enter recovery mode by guessing. See this video: https://youtu.be/0nDLvy8F5qk and click buttons exactly as he says.